# Cannot invoke function with an argument list of type '()'

Tags: ios, swift

I'm new to IOS development. The constructor of AVAudioRecorder is  `AVAudioRecorder(URL: filePath, settings: nil, error: nil)` in the resource that I'm following but I'm coding in Swift 2 which has different constructor.

The error **Cannot invoke function with an argument list of type '()'** occurs on "`try audioRecorder = AVAudioRecorder(URL: filePath, settings: nil)`" line

This is my record audio file :

```
@IBAction func recordAudio(sender: UIButton) {
    stopButton.hidden = false
    recordButton.enabled = false
    recordingInProgress.hidden = false
    let dirPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as String

    let currentDateTime = NSDate()
    let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "ddMMyyyy-HHmmss"
    let recordingName = formatter.stringFromDate(currentDateTime)+".wav"
    let pathArray = [dirPath, recordingName]
    let filePath = NSURL.fileURLWithPathComponents(pathArray)
    print(filePath)

    var session = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
    do {
        try session.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord)

    } catch {}

    do {
        try audioRecorder = AVAudioRecorder(URL: filePath, settings: nil)
    } catch {}

    audioRecorder.meteringEnabled = true
    audioRecorder.prepareToRecord()
    audioRecorder.record()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way of initializing `AVAudioRecorder` using its initializer in Swift 2 is to leave out the parameter of type `NSErrorPointer` and catch it:

```
do 
{
    audioRecorder = try AVAudioRecorder(URL:filePath, settings:[:])
} 
catch let error as NSError
{
    printf(error.description)
}
```

Comment: New error popped up now  `value of optional 'NSURL?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'`

Comment: I tried your code (Xcode 7), but have a BAD ACCESS Error in this line. `audioRecorder = try AVAudioRecorder(URL:filePath!,settings:[:])`    Somehow Xcode suggested `filePath!` with exclamation mark here. Do I have to change the `dirPath` in a way?      `let dirPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as String`

Answer (score 0):

You are missing error part of the audio recorder initializer:

`audioRecorder = AVAudioRecorder(URL: filePath, settings: nil, error: nil)`

Comment: It is not initialized like this in swift 2. Check this [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioRecorder_ClassReference/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/AVAudioRecorder/initWithURL:settings:error:)